# How to remove label on node in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nosql

On some of the nodes, I put a label of "Englist" instead of "English".  When I tried to relabeling it, I added a new label "English".  Now I have both labels on the node.

How do I get rid of the "Englist" label?  Without Deleting the node.

Answer (score 7):

For future reference on this and other things, the [Cypher ref card](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/) is invaluable.

You want the REMOVE command, specifying the bound variable and the label to remove.

For your case:

```
MATCH (e:Englist)
REMOVE e:Englist
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked.
For next time, I make a typo on the label, is they a way I can change it? without making a new label and removing the old one?

Comment: There is no way to change a label from one thing to another in a single command, but you can do a match as above, set the label using `SET e:English', then remove the bad label.

Comment: To expand on that, the reason is that multiple labels on nodes are very useful. As such, there is no restriction that nodes must have a single label, so a command to change one label to another isn't useful or desired, especially as you can get that same functionality by explicitly matching on the bad label, removing it, and adding the correct label.